# How to change destination ranges when using autofill in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I am quite new to VBA, I am making a macro where it copies data from 'Sample' workbook to 'Etracker' workbook. After copying cell "H11" from 'Sample' to the last row of C column in Etracker, I want C column to autofill down to until where data is in J column. the code works but where it says "C16926" now, it changes every time because I constantly entering data into it. so I want to autofill it from last row in column C all the time.
I tried different ways to change "C16926" to vary but it doesn't seem to work. 
Please help! and thanks in advance.

```
LastrowC = Etracker.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
LastrowJ = Etracker.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Sample.Activate
Range("H11").Copy
Etracker.Cells(LastrowC, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Etracker.Activate
Etracker.Range("C" & LastrowC).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C16926:C" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillCopy
```

Comment: you need to explain what you expect `C16926` to be? We cannot know to what it should change to if you don't tell us. • You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I want to change "C16926" to be the last data in column C. in other words, I want this macro to select the last data in C column and autofill to where the last data is in J column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to concatenate your last row into the address like

```
"C" & LastrowC & ":C" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Note that you don't need to `.Select` or `.Activate` if you specify a worksheet for **every** `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns` object. Using  `.Select` or `.Activate` is very unreliable and makes your code really slow.

So you should end up with something like

```
Dim LastRowC As Long
LastrowC = Etracker.Cells(Etracker.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Dim LastrowJ As Long
LastrowJ = Etracker.Cells(Etracker.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Sample.Range("H11").Copy
Etracker.Cells(LastrowC, "C").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Etracker.Range("C" & LastrowC).AutoFill Destination:=Etracker.Range("C" & LastrowC & ":C" & LastrowJ), Type:=xlFillCopy
```

Comment: I am using LastrowJ to find where lastrow is at  when I copy stuff from 'sample' to J column in 'Etracker' and then after copying J column, I want to autofill column C to where last data is at in J column. I can see how it will work however, when I use "C" & LastrowC & ":C" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) , for some reason, Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row grabs ramdom row 23, would you know why it would do that? thanks

Comment: To add: I realized Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row changes and grabs the last cell from 'sample' worksheet when I am executing to copy a data from that sheet

Comment: Because if you just use `Range` then Excel cannot know in which sheet to look and it guesses. So you need always to specify a worksheet  (as I have written in my second sentence of my answer). If you use `Etracker.Range` then Excel know to look in worksheet `Etracker` for that range. Make sure you always tell VBA which sheet the range is in. Otherwise you might get random results.

Comment: I see, now it works very well, Thank you so much for your help. one more thing to ask, when concatenating ranges, not sure when to use " ", Would you be able to clarify that part?

Comment: Not really sure what exactly you mean, but everything that is text/string must be enclosed in `" "` everything that should be considered as a variable/object must be without them.